# C++ fast file reading line by line

Tags: c++

I want to create a simple .OBJ parser. Code below works, but is slow. Im testing it with a 26MB file and it takes about 22 seconds to parse it. If i commented out the lines seen in the code, the time went to 17 seconds. It takes 17 seconds to iterate the file line by line and to extract data. Is there any way i can make it faster? I also tried reading the file into memory and then parsing it. It became slower.

```
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        if (line[0] == 'v') {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            std::string type;
            GLfloat x, y, z;
            iss >> type >> x >> y >> z;
            if (type.compare("v") == 0) {
                //vertices.push_back(x);
                //vertices.push_back(y);
                //vertices.push_back(z);
            }
            else if (type.compare("vn") == 0) {
                //normals.push_back(x);
                //normals.push_back(y);
                //normals.push_back(z);
            }
            else if (type.compare("vt") == 0) {
                //UVs.push_back(x);
                //UVs.push_back(y);
            }
        }
        else if (line[0] == 'f') {
            unsigned int size = out_vertices.size() / 3;
            unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
            sscanf_s(line.c_str(),
                "f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d",
                &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0],
                &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1],
                &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2]);

            /*GLfloat* vertex = &vertices[(vertexIndex[0] - 1) * 3];
            out_vertices.insert(out_vertices.end(), vertex, vertex + 3);

            vertex = &vertices[(vertexIndex[1] - 1) * 3];
            out_vertices.insert(out_vertices.end(), vertex, vertex + 3);

            vertex = &vertices[(vertexIndex[2] - 1) * 3];
            out_vertices.insert(out_vertices.end(), vertex, vertex + 3);

            GLfloat* uv = &UVs[(uvIndex[0] - 1) * 2];
            out_UVs.insert(out_UVs.end(), uv, uv + 2);

            uv = &UVs[(uvIndex[1] - 1) * 2];
            out_UVs.insert(out_UVs.end(), uv, uv + 2);

            uv = &UVs[(uvIndex[2] - 1) * 2];
            out_UVs.insert(out_UVs.end(), uv, uv + 2);

            GLfloat* normal = &normals[(normalIndex[0] - 1) * 3];
            out_normals.insert(out_normals.end(), normal, normal + 3);

            normal = &normals[(normalIndex[1] - 1) * 3];
            out_normals.insert(out_normals.end(), normal, normal + 3);

            normal = &normals[(normalIndex[2] - 1) * 3];
            out_normals.insert(out_normals.end(), normal, normal + 3);


            out_indices.push_back(size);
            out_indices.push_back(size + 1);
            out_indices.push_back(size + 2);*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: What compiler and build options are you using?

Comment: Could you upload somewhere your big file? I'd like to see what happens. 1st rule of speed optimization - profile slow. Have you done any profiling to see where do you spend the most of time? And if the time spent ion getline, I'd assure that file reads are caching forward or switch to memory mapped file.

Comment: You'll see a list of suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better . If you even better performance, you'll need to go into Win32 API handling or use the Boost library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get IOStream to perform better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166263/how-to-get-iostream-to-perform-better)

Comment: @LiMar http://www.cadnav.com/3d-models/model-50432.html this is the model.

Comment: @underscore_d the one visual studio 2019 defaults to.

Comment: What generated the OBJ file?  Compilers can generate "obj" files and each have proprietary formats.

Comment: Your biggest bottleneck is reading from the file.  Reading from the file requires start up time, time to find the file (seek time), then time to read the data from the file.  The startup and seek occur for every transaction.  You can improve the read speed by increasing the amount of data per transaction.  For example, one read transaction of 2048 bytes is more efficient than 2048 requests to read 1 byte.  Also search the internet for "memory mapped files" and see if your OS supports them.

Comment: Another bottleneck is the (re)allocation of memory for the vector.  You can reduce the number of reallocations by allocating a large size for the vector at definition (look at the constructors for `std::vector`).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it is a 3D model. Wavefront OBJ format. I simplified the original by importing exporting it to blender and makeing all the faces a triangle.

Comment: Probably next in line is the conversion of formatted text or parsing.  One way around this is to have the file created with fixed length records.  Fixed length allows you to jump to locations in the string without parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the file into smaller chunks and reading from those chunks might be able to speed up your processing.

Here is what I think might be able to help you:

[File Split Into Threads](http://paste.lisp.org/display/133861#1)

[Similar topic on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484184/c-how-to-chunk-a-file-for-simultaneous-async-processing)

Thanks

Comment: Chunking migh help. ALthough threading migh be difficult, as the order of lines is important.

Comment: Okay. 
What if you add a line number to the large file. 
Do a file split and then a multi-threaded read/processing 
and then using those line numbers put the data back in order 
Does it help ?

Answer (score 1):

First, and most important. Rebuild your software in "Release"-mode, not in "Debug"-mode. Or, switch on optimization options on manually.

Then, after opening the file, add the following statements, after the stream is open:

```
constexpr size_t SizeOfIOStreamBuffer = 100'000;
static char ioBuffer[SizeOfIOStreamBuffer];
file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(ioBuffer, SizeOfIOStreamBuffer);
```

Then, for your `std::vector`s, please call their `reserve(50000U)` function.

I expect a execution time to be 1 second. (On my machine with 50MB file it was)

Please try and feed back.

Comment: Tested just release mode. and got 1 second. reserver and buffersize didnt make any difference.

Comment: having just worked on an issue exactly like this, I suggest trying a bunch of different buffer sizes.  There is always a sweet spot.

Answer (score 0):

This how I did to optimize this code...

**Environment** : MacBook Pro, macos, Xcode for IDE. Built-in Instruments for profiling.
**Target File**: downloaded cadnav-200615151218.rar from link you provided. Extracted APC.obj(~17M) and work on it.

**Step 1** - reproduce the problem
Add missing bits to the code:

```
typedef float GLfloat;
void reader()
{
    std::ifstream file("/Users/mlifshits/Downloads/APC.obj");
```

Comment out `unsigned int si_ze = out_vertices.size() / 3;` since it is not used anywhere and the type of out_vertices unknown.

Profile:

took 537ms, time hogs: operator>>(&float), getline, scanf

[image: step 1]

**Step 2** - attack first time hog which is `>>(&float)`

Use `sscanf()` in place of `iss`

Profile:

took 371ms (improvement!), hogs: scanf and getline
[image: step 2]

**Steps 3 and 4** - attack the hogs!

looked up online about scanf and found that it's slow in reading floats. Replaced with "naive loop" from https://tinodidriksen.com/2011/05/cpp-convert-string-to-double-speed/

since getline hog is so hungry because of multiple allocations (seen in profiler), replaced it with C code using fopen() and fgets()

Profile:
took 166ms (vs 546 initially!), hogs still scanf and fgets.

[image: step 3-4]

**Optimize more?** - possible very much. I stop here.

Code:
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
typedef float GLfloat;

//https://tinodidriksen.com/uploads/code/cpp/speed-string-to-double.cpp
float naive_atof(const char *p) {
    float r = 0.0;
    bool neg = false;
    if (*p == '-') {
        neg = true;
        ++p;
    }
    while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
        r = (r*10.0) + (*p - '0');
        ++p;
    }
    if (*p == '.') {
        float f = 0.0;
        int n = 0;
        ++p;
        while (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
            f = (f*10.0) + (*p - '0');
            ++p;
            ++n;
        }
        r += f / std::pow(10.0, n);
    }
    if (neg) {
        r = -r;
    }
    return r;
}

void reader()
{
    char line[256] = {0};
    std::string type;
    char xyz[3][100] = {0};
    FILE*fp = fopen("/Users/limar/Downloads/APC.obj", "r");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        if (line[0] == 'v') {
            GLfloat x, y, z;
            sscanf(line,"%s %s %s %s", (char*)type.c_str(), xyz[0], xyz[1], xyz[2]);
            x = naive_atof(xyz[0]);
            y = naive_atof(xyz[1]);
            z = naive_atof(xyz[2]);
            if (type.compare("v") == 0) {
                //vertices.push_back(x);
                //vertices.push_back(y);
                //vertices.push_back(z);
            }
            else if (type.compare("vn") == 0) {
                //normals.push_back(x);
                //normals.push_back(y);
                //normals.push_back(z);
            }
            else if (type.compare("vt") == 0) {
                //UVs.push_back(x);
                //UVs.push_back(y);
            }
        }
        else if (line[0] == 'f') {
            //unsigned int size = out_vertices.size() / 3;
            unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
            sscanf(line,
                "f %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d",
                &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0],
                &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1],
                &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2]);

            /*GLfloat* vertex = &vertices[(vertexIndex[0] - 1) * 3];
            out_vertices.insert(out_vertices.end(), vertex, vertex + 3);

            vertex = &vertices[(vertexIndex[1] - 1) * 3];
            out_vertices.insert(out_vertices.end(), vertex, vertex + 3);

            vertex = &vertices[(vertexIndex[2] - 1) * 3];
            out_vertices.insert(out_vertices.end(), vertex, vertex + 3);

            GLfloat* uv = &UVs[(uvIndex[0] - 1) * 2];
            out_UVs.insert(out_UVs.end(), uv, uv + 2);

            uv = &UVs[(uvIndex[1] - 1) * 2];
            out_UVs.insert(out_UVs.end(), uv, uv + 2);

            uv = &UVs[(uvIndex[2] - 1) * 2];
            out_UVs.insert(out_UVs.end(), uv, uv + 2);

            GLfloat* normal = &normals[(normalIndex[0] - 1) * 3];
            out_normals.insert(out_normals.end(), normal, normal + 3);

            normal = &normals[(normalIndex[1] - 1) * 3];
            out_normals.insert(out_normals.end(), normal, normal + 3);

            normal = &normals[(normalIndex[2] - 1) * 3];
            out_normals.insert(out_normals.end(), normal, normal + 3);


            out_indices.push_back(size);
            out_indices.push_back(size + 1);
            out_indices.push_back(size + 2);*/
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    reader();
    return 0;
}
```